# Using regex to remove comma and whitespaces and divide them in different variables

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, command-line-arguments

Is there any efficient way of doing this?

**I want to pass the arg to command line and divide them to following:**

1. String[] command
2. String[] word
3. String[] fileName

**Example:**

```
String[] arg = {"-b", "-f", "-i", "Dog", "Cat", "--", "fileName1.txt", "fileName2.txt", "fileName3.txt"};
Main.main(arg);

String[] arg = {"-f", "-i", "Hi", "Hello", "--", "fileName1.txt", "fileName2.txt"};
Main.main(arg);

String[] arg = {"-i", "Hi", "Hello", "--", "fileName2.txt"};
Main.main(arg);
```

**NOTE:**

```
Syntax:  "[-b] [-f] [-l] [-i]  <from> <to> -- " + "fileName"
```

**In syntax -** command, word -- fileName

"--" it will be in between  and file name everytime.

I have done the following code which is not efficient. Using String.split(" ") and dividing again and again to different arrays of string which is not efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never understand the desire to use regexes for simple things like this. Why not just create three lists and loop over the arguments while splitting them into the right list?

```
ArrayList<String> flags = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
for (String arg : args) {
    if (arg.equals("--")) {
        continue;
    }
    if (arg.contains(".")) {
        files.add(arg);
    }else if (arg.contains("-")) {
        flags.add(arg);
    }else {
        words.add(arg);
    }
}
```

Once you have all the arguments split up by type you can easily do whatever you want with them or rearrange them as you wish. This is more efficient than a regex as well.

Comment: I have a problem its adding "--" in flags which I dont want. I can remove the last element from flags everytime. But is there another way ?

Comment: @topper1309 You could just ignore it by changing the if statement to something like `if (arg.contains("-") && !arg.equals("--"))`

Comment: can we skip "--" because then it will add to else part,

Comment: @topper1309 I added a `continue` statement at the top that should skip lines equal to "--".